# Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use

Tags: react-native, navigation, components, yarnpkg, npx

I use `createBottomTabNavigator`.

In my class

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator({
  MainScreen: { screen: MainScreen },
  SecondScreen: { screen: SecondScreen }
});

const Container = createAppContainer(Tab);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isReady: false
  };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this._load();
  };
  render() {
    const { isReady } = this.state;
    if (!isReady) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }
    return <Container />;
  }
  _load = async () => {
    try {
      this.setState({ isReady: true });
    } catch (error) {}
  };
}
```

This is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "3.0.8"
  }
```

This is my error

```
Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. 

* Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
* If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps.
* Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: SafeView
```

I did `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It keeps happening even after using `react-navigation` 3.x with latest React version because `react-navigation` depends on `"@react-navigation/native": "^3.6.2"`, which uses`"react-native-safe-area-view":"0.11"` where `SafeAreaView` uses deprecated methods.

> 4.0.x version of @react-navigation/native uses 0.14 which has been updated

So upgrade your react-navigation. Hope it helps. feel free for doubts